# Why can't I add these points as traces to my simulation in LTSpice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation

I'm trying to simulate the voltages in this circuit:

[image: pic of circuit]

The Vo and v3 traces show fine, but v1 and v2 refuse to do anything. When I try to add them manually it says they don't exist. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` are all the same node.  The software recognizes that and only uses one of them.  Did you mean to put the labels on the left sides of those resistors?

Comment: @SteKulov yes, thanks, they work on the other side. I had tried that before and it didn't work, but since then I changed some other parts of the circuit and it all works together now

Comment: Just make sure you understand that it should only work like that.  What you tried to do makes no sense because they are all the same node while the left side of the resistors are all unique and therefore are all different nodes.

Comment: Note that v1, v2, v3 are also the names of the three generators. It should be confusing to use that names ... And it is logical that they work at the left of the 3 resistors.